# Allow a role to edit one specific plugin

Tags: plugins, user-roles

Is there any way to allow a particular role (Contributors, in this case) to use one plugin, and one plugin only?

I would like them to be able to add images to a gallery when writing their post, but the gallery is a plugin that they have no access to.

I don't want them to have access to other plugins.

Thanks in advance for any help :)

**Edit:** I have added the capability to `manage_options` and users can now see the plugin that I want them to in the menu. But, when the user hovers over the item in the menu to expand the sub-menu, they cannot see the top two items that me (an admin) can see. Why is this? Is it a plugin related issue?

Also, I have been looking into the [`add_menu_page` function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page) - could this help me? I don't really understand where to put the code so if someone could help me out then that would be great. I'm not 100% on the parameters for it either.

They can also see some other plugins but I will probably just hide them from the menu so that they can't be seen by the user.

Comment: I'm not sure you mean *to edit* the plugin code or *to use* the plugin?

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't very obvious. I mean use. :)

Answer (score -1):

To solve this you need to go into the main `.php` file for the plugin and have changed the required capability using `add_menu_page`.

I created a custom capability, added it to Contributors, and changed the `.php` file to allow users with that capability to view the menu.

Comment: plugin code should never be changed, unless you are ready to maintain it yourself.